# Add another AD group during domain join

Tags: windows, active-directory, active-directory-group

I don't even know if this is possible because I can't find anything anywhere about it but are you able to specify the groups that are added to the Local Administrators group during a domain join? like in addition to Domain Admins. I know I can do it with group policy but sometimes that isn't fast enough, right after a domain join the second group isn't always added which forces the techs to have to log in locally with admin rights and specify their domain account to connect to a network share in order to install software required by that PC.

Comment: Depends on what is doing the domain join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPO is the way to go. You could do a `gpupdate /force` or you could do a reboot and have the computer GPO reapplied.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured the answer would be. I was just looking to see if it was possible. Thanks